# Android Java Justified tablerow in linear layout

Tags: java, android, layout, android-linearlayout, tablerow

I have a table row in a linear layout
The table row is set to fill parent
I have three objects inside the tablerow a textview then a editbox and then a buttong
they all line up horizontally

i want the textview on the left to be fixed at 100p width
I want the button on the right to be fixed at 50dp width

how do i set the editbox in the middle so that all three fill the width of the screen which might vary from device to device

I have tried various combinations of match and wrap but cant seem to get it

Any ideas

Mark

Answer (score 0):

That's when **LAYOUT WEIGHTS** come in handy.

- For the fixed elements, just assign `width` & `height` as usual.
- For the elastic ones, **set "0dp" as the size you want to be elastic**, and enter a `weight` in the weight field (layout parameters of a `linearlayout`).

Which `weight`?

If you only have one elastic element, it doesnt matter. If you have 2, then the available space *will be distributed proportionally between weights*. So if you wanted 2 elastic elements, one twice the size of the other, you'd assign weights 1 & 2.

By the way, heavy use of `LinearLayouts` with `weight` are somewhat discouraged because it takes Android twice the time to calculate their size. If your table has a lot of rows, you will certainly notice it's not as fast as fixed elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use layout_weight for particular child of your view group or use relativelayout may solve your problem and please post you layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, using `layout_weight`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```